# WPF data binding does not work

Tags: wpf, data-binding, textbox

This is my data binding from a string (History.current_commad) to a text box (tbCommand):

```
        history = new History();

        Binding bind = new Binding("Command");

        bind.Source = history;
        bind.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        bind.Path = new PropertyPath("current_command");
        bind.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;

        // myDatetext is a TextBlock object that is the binding target object
        tbCommand.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, bind);
        history.current_command = "test";
```

history.current_command is changing but the text box is not being update. What is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What does the `History` class look like?

Comment: public class History { public string current_command; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you don't see the change reflected in the `TextBlock` is because `current_command` is just a field, so the `Binding` doesn't know when it's been udpated.

The easiest way to fix that is to have your `History` class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, convert `current_command` to a property, and then raise the `PropertyChanged` event in the setter of your property:

```
public class History : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }

    private string _current_command;
    public string current_command
    {
        get
        {
            return _current_command;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_current_command == null || !_current_command.Equals(value))
            {
                // Change the value and notify that the property has changed
                _current_command = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("current_command");
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Now, when you assign a value to the `current_command`, the event will fire, and the `Binding` will know to update its target as well.

If you find yourself with a lot of classes where you'd like to bind to their properties, you should consider moving the event and the helper method into a base class, so that you don't write the same code repeatedly.

Comment: Hi @dlev, can you have a look at this problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130143/wpf-xmlns-the-clr-namespace-uri-refers-to-a-namespace-that-is-not-included-in The reason I'm doing data binding in code is I could not get the xmlns thing right. Thanks